# Liveness detection for dynamic objects

Tags: computer-vision

I'm new to computer vision and I'm trying to understand if there is such a thing as "liveness detection" (real versus image of) for "objects" that are dynamic by nature (something that either has no width/lenght/height or no correlation between its subcomponents (like eyes/mouth in the context of a face)

My use case is: Using a single or stereo camera detect wether the smoke seen in the feed is real or fake (seen on TV, in a painting on the wall, etc)

I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction regarding how this can be achieved (if possible)

Comment: smoke "seen on tv", how does that differ from real smoke, other than the former is a picture on a screen? do you mean to discuss that specific example, or is that secondary to the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.